# What is the simplest configuration to supply a small number of CNAMEs internally to an AWS VPC

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, vpc

I have a multi-server, multi-part application I am moving to the cloud. I am using Elastic Load Balancing (ELB) to share load over instances of the same type and to handle port forwarding. ELBs (even internal ones) get a generated dns name and due to the implementation of ELB the ip is not reliable. The normal recommendation is to use Route 53, dyndns or similar to setup public aliases. This works nicely in most cases, and indeed, works for my external access to the load balancers.

My problems comes as I want to reduce (if not eliminate) the configuration differences between the multiple VPCs I am using for dev(s), test(s), staging and prod. I can do that if I am able to provide aliases for the ELBs for use within the VPC.

Essentially I want to set up CNAMEs for internal use only, but with a minimum of stuffing around. This means I need:

- Easy installation (ideally RPM)
- Easy configuration (command line interface would be nice, or at least a small number of files). I will need to generate the config at create time to pickup the newly created ELB dns names.

I have looked at:

- BIND - The config is icky but if I can get a config file with *<-- insert CNAMES here* that would work.
- Dnsmasq - nice config and I use it at home but major restrictions on CNAMEs means it isn't usable.
- TinyDNS/djbdns - Manual build and install, RPMs not available, and FAQ helpfully says 
  *"Compiling djbdns yourself is trivial. If you feel you are not up to
  it, please reconsider if you should be administrating a name server."*

Any ideas?

Comment: What did you end up using as a solution? What about `dnsmasq` made it unsuitable?

Comment: Dnsmasq can only create CNAMES for A records it creates. As the A records were generated by Amazon this meant that dnsmasq was not an option. In the end Amazon effectively solved the problem when they introduced A-aliases for ELBs in Route53. This meant I could use Route53 for the ELBs and dnsmasq internal to the VPC to manage the server names. End result still not *exactly* what I was after as I had to use the external alias for the ELBs rather than the more ideal internal name but that was handled with a little custom config file for each VPC.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an RPM, why not look at using something like [Salt](http://docs.saltstack.org/en/latest/topics/index.html),[Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/), or [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/)? The setup process isn't too difficult, and it would allow you to setup environments based on the hostname(dev, test, staging, prod), and then push unique configuration values, while keeping the overall configuration identical.